# Displaying only one key value pair using .map in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React JS. I'm trying to display the name key-value pair for each object in my array. Each object has 2 keys, and currently, when I run my project, it displays the name duplicated. I just want to remove the second display, and only map the name for each object to the console, the URL is simply a href. Here's my component:

```
export default function JSArticles() {
  return <List>
    {NEXT_JS_COOL_SITES?.map((info) => {
      return Object.keys(info).map((index) => (  
         <ListItem key={index}><a href={info.url}><Typography>{info.name}</Typography></a></ListItem> 
      ))      
    })}
  </List>
}
```

Here is the current output:
[project output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCToW.png)

And for reference, here is my object list:

```
const NEXT_JS_COOL_SITES = [
  {
    name: "Next.js Blog",
    url: "https://nextjs.org/blog"
  },
  {
    name: "Awesome React Components to take a look at",
    url: "https://github.com/brillout/awesome-react-components"
  },
  {
    name: "Building IOS and Android Apps with React",
    url: "https://reactnative.dev/"
  },
  {
    name: "React Conference Talks on Youtube",
    url: "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=react+conference+talks"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide more info about your `info` object and what is the situation about duplicated name?

Comment: You probably don't need to map over the keys of `info`.

Comment: I have it updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the inner map. The outer one is already iterating over the objects in your array. You can also destructure the `info` object to `url` and `name` to make it a bit cleaner. Like this:

```
{NEXT_JS_COOL_SITES?.map(({ url, name }, index) => 
   <ListItem key={index}>
     <a href={url}>
       <Typography>{name}</Typography>
     </a>
   </ListItem> 
)}
```

But using `index` as `key` is not ideal. I'd recommend using a unique value that won't depend on the order. You could use `url` in this case.

Comment: This really helped simplify it in my brain as well. This is incredibly helpful, I really appreciate you taking a few minutes to help. Cheers mate!